# What does BC date mean in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

In my table in the database I have a column of the `timestamp without time zone` type. And rows contains the following values:

```
         end_date
 ---------------------------
 timestamp without time zone

  2774-04-18 22:59:49.88 BC
  2015-04-07 06:06:21.738
  2015-04-02 12:37:15.161
  2015-03-26 15:58:45.864
  2015-04-09 15:34:41.399
```

As far as BC means Before Christ. How can I convert that `BC` to non-`BC` timestamp? I was confused that `end_date > now()` fails on  `2774-04-18 22:59:49.88 BC`. Why that?

Comment: Obvious answer, add 2774 years and it will be AD?

Comment: With end_date effectively being -4789 years it will obviously be smaller than `now()`.

Comment: @Wolph SO 2000-11-11 BC is actuall -2000?

Comment: @user3663882 Think about it: 2000 BC is 4000 years ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means **before Christ** - the limits for `timestamp` in postgresql are:

- low:    4713 BC
- high: 294276 AD

Just to show the scale: Egyptian pyramids  were built starting around 2500 before Christ.

The `date` type goes a bit further into the future - future proof? [see here for date types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: 294276 AD (timestamp), or 5874897 AD (date), or 178000000 years (interval) - I believe that I'll sleep easily without any Y2K or [Y2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) problems. +1.

Comment: I am sorry, but what does the value 5874897 [AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domini) mean? Which year, month, day, please?

Comment: @HansGinzel it mean the year 5874897.

Comment: @HansGinzel, as ypercube mentioned, it is the year 5,874,897.  More specifically the maximum allowed date is Dec 31st in the year 5874897, which you can test with the query: select '5874897-12-31'::date;  and select '5874897-12-31'::date + interval '1 day'; The latter query fails with "Error: date out of range for timestamp"